# rails consoleにて、モデル名.allはActiveRecord Relationを返すメソッドなのにDBアクセスしている、これは正しい？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

いろんな記事をみていると、ActiveRecordの、allやwhereは、ActiveRecord::Relationのオブジェクトを返すメソッドで実際にDBにアクセスしていないって話なんですが、
試しに自分のrails consoleで試したところ普通にDBにアクセスして取得できているんですよね。

```
Recruiter.all 
=>   Recruiter Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "recruiters".* FROM "recruiters"
[#<Recruiter:0x000055e9db560f48
  id: "0abf31a2-e39f-472a-bb8f-fcb3016d62f8",
  last_name: "foo",
  first_name: "bar",
  email: "foo@example.com",
  created_at: Wed, 09 Feb 2022 17:57:33 JST +09:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 09 Feb 2022 17:57:33 JST +09:00,
  phone_number: "0010002000">]
```

ログをみても、普通にSQLが発行されています。

```
  Recruiter Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "recruiters".* FROM "recruiters"
```

ですが、一方でloaded?を実行するとfalseがかえるんですよね。

```
Recruiter.all.loaded?
=> false
```

自分が期待する動きは、Recruiter.allをしてもDBにアクセスせずSQLも発行しないはずなんですが、間違っていますか？

Answer (score 2):

> ActiveRecordの、allやwhereは、ActiveRecord::Relationのオブジェクトを返すメソッドで実際にDBにアクセスしていないって話なんですが、
> :
> 自分が期待する動きは、Recruiter.allをしてもDBにアクセスせずSQLも発行しないはずなんですが、間違っていますか？

その認識が誤ってるわけではありません。`ActiveRecord::Relation`オブジェクトは実際に評価されるタイミングで初めてDBにアクセスします。

ではなぜそう見えないかというと、

1. コンソールで`Recruiter.all`を実行
2. `ActiveRecord::Relation`オブジェクトが帰ってくる
3. コンソールはオブジェクトを画面に表示するため"#inspect"を呼ぶ
4. `ActiveRecord::Relation`オブジェクトはDBにアクセスしにいく

となっているからです。一方で`Recruiter.all.loaded?`の場合は、コンソールが表示するのは`Recruiter.all.loaded?`の結果なので、DBにはアクセスしません。

`result=Recruiter.all`してから`result`を呼ぶとそのタイミングでDBにアクセスしてるのがわかると思います。